# How do I put a border: 1px solid #ddd around a selectbox using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frameworks

I need your help,

Alot of the websites do some really neat fancy work around using the jQuery framework to style their selectboxes. As we know it, I am stuck using ie7 at work and I would like to put a 1px solid #ddd border around my selectbox (this must be compatible for ie7). I know that ie7 doesn't support the css on its own.

How do I go about styling my select box using jQuery to achieve this?

```
<select>
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="january">January</option>
    <option value="february">February</option>
    <option value="march">March</option>
    <option value="april">April</option>
    <option value="may">May</option>
    <option value="june">June</option>
    <option value="july">July</option>
    <option value="august">August</option>
    <option value="september">September</option>
    <option value="october">October</option>
    <option value="november">November</option>
    <option value="december">December</option>
</select>
```

If there is also a quick an lightweight way to also style the drop down's border to the same color as the border in the selectbox that too would awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why don't you try `bootstrap select` or `jquery-ui` ?

Comment: I think google can solve this for you...

Comment: The sites you speak of almost certainly aren't styling the `select`. They are replacing it with a styled `div` or other element. That's how most of the jquery plugins do it. For example http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the [jQuery-Selectbox](http://marcj.github.io/jquery-selectBox/) plugin**. You can transform normal `<select>` elements into nice styleable HTML ones.

Link to the JS file:

```
<script src="jquery.selectbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add the CSS file (or append contents to your own stylesheet):

```
<link href="jquery.selectbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

To initialize:

```
// default
$('select').selectBox();

// or with custom settings
$('select').selectBox({
    mobile: true,
    menuSpeed: 'fast'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the jQuery-UI Selectable plugin from [here](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/).

If you are looking to style the default `<select>` I think [Link 1](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) and 
[Link 2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sNwrs/596/) how far anyone has ever been able to get.

You might also want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript) question on SO.